how to unpack nexus-maven-repository-index.gz by indexer-cli-7.x?
I want to build an application on my computer to quickly retrieve Maven coordinates. Like Jetbrains IDEA, which can download nexus-maven-repository-index.gz and use it locally.
But I followed the steps at Maven Central Index Docment and found that the index was over 20GB using indexer-client 5.1.1.
But in IDEA, it was only around 2GB. I suspect it's the indexer-client version (it references a different lucene version). But when I use indexer-cli-7.1.4-cli.jar, the same command fails to unpack the index files. What I missed?
Thanks!
# I executed the following command and got a folder with more than 20GB.
java -jar indexer-cli-5.1.1.jar --unpack nexus-maven-repository-index.gz --destination central-lucene-index --type full

# I executed the following command, but I got nothing. Only write.lock created in central-lucene-index folder.
java -jar indexer-cli-7.1.4-cli.jar --unpack nexus-maven-repository-index.gz --destination central-lucene-index --type full

I got the indexer-cli-7.1.4-cli.jar in Maven Repository

Maybe you are better off using a REST API instead of downloading the whole index.

Thanks. But this goes against my original intention of building the repository locally.

What should your application actually do?

Actually I want to know how IDEA retrieves Maven position so quickly。And I want to provide a simple website that only allows quick search of Maven positions, without being as heavy as the Maven official repository.
